# Can't get BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I come here because i really don't understand why i don't get the BroadcastReceiver
I have a service called NotifService which creates notifications.
i created a receiver following this code :

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

Intent myIntent;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.d("2erlog","2erlog>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
     myIntent = new Intent(context, NotifService.class);
     context.startService(myIntent);
     Log.d("3erlog","3erlog>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    }
}
```

And here you can see my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.notifplugunplug"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <service android:name="NotifService"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.notifplugunplug.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- Declaring broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED event -->
    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver" android:enabled="true"     android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>



  </application>
</manifest>
```

I know that the service never start because i never see logs i created and i don't see notifications appear from the service.

Thank you guys !

Comment: Have you ever run the application? i.e. launched the MainActivity?

Comment: Yep the main activity was used to start the service to test if the problem was my broadcast receiver or somewhere else. And the activity starts well (but i put in comment the startactivity in order to do it from the broadcastReceiver) !

Comment: Where is your app installed? Internal memory or SD card? If it's SD card the `BOOT_COMPLETED`action will be being sent before the SD card is mounted and your app won't be active.

Comment: i currently start my app in Eclipse with AVD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" is a global broadcast.
Since you have defined your BroadcastReceiver as android:exported="false" it will get only local broadcast.
Change it to android:exported="true".

Answer (score 1):

Place your broadcast reciever in a different package 
Your package is com.example.notifplugunplug
Then right click on it and create a new package under it 
com.example.notifplugunplug.myreciever
Then place your broadcast reciever under it

Comment: It doesn't change anything :x